# Software for recoding primevideo

Tags: screen-recording

I use ShareX to screen record. But I noticed when I tried doing that on recording the video
being played on primevideo.com that I only heard the sound and no video. The video is blank. What could be the reason for this? Is there an alternative way to record?

Comment: "*What could be the reason for this?*" You are obviously trying to record licensed content protected by DRM

Comment: Yes, but there must be a workaround. How do they stop it?